# vba sort and filter using range objects

Tags: vba, sorting, autofilter

I have data that I need to sort multiple columns and then filter by 0/1, I'd like to simply use any sheet and find the column address which I've done:

```
Dim ColName1 As Variant
Set ColName1 = sht.Cells.Find("name of column").Address
```

I can use this for a portion of the sort command, but I'm trying to set another Varient or String = Left(sht.Cells.Find("name of column").Address,2) which removes the $1 from $K$1 but when input into the sort command, it doesn't like it.  Do I need to use another type to define ColName1?  Or define a 2nd item as int/something else?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(ColName1.Address & ":K" & LastRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal          'categ / material
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test").sort
        .SetRange Range(UsedRange)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

I have multiple columns to sort so I'd like to make this dynamic and eventually throw it into an interface where I just read in a file and use the user defined variable/objects to define the columns to sort.

Also, I read a lot about not referencing the current ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets but when I try to define something like

```
Set sht = ActiveSheet
```

it only works for some things but not the sht.sort ??  What am I missing...

Answer (score 0):

Sorting in VBA is unduly painful. Here is how I would approach this:

```
Sub TestSort()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim SortCol  As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Set Sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
SortCol = Sht.Cells.Find("Name of Column").Column
Sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(2, SortCol), Cells(LastRow, SortCol))
With Sht.Sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```